# Unable to load the requested class: Config (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am really new to CodeIgniter, so if this is a no brainer question, it is what it is. I just recently had to download a website whole directory thats already in its beta phases, so its been built out already mostly. So I am jumping in having to learn this new framework and im learning the hard way.

When I try and run it locally, i get the message "`Unable to load the requested class: Config`"

Would this be a controller? I have no idea where to even begin to look for this error... Really need direction on this one.

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: i honestly wouldnt know what to post.

Comment: ( didnt write the code myself)

Comment: Ok - well welcome to Codeigniter Eddie. Maybe good to establish a few things like... 1. What version of CI you are running... The fastest way - Look in system/core/CodeIgniter.php. and 2. What environment are you running on... OS and Server type etc...

Comment: Also definitely recommend you have a good read over the user guide to get your feet wet.

Comment: @EddieTaliaferro Your post needs work. Presumably you are attempting to access the CI installation by entering some url in your browser, for instance? Are you running apache on your local machine or something? You need to provide specific details about urls, environment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Linux server` then it caused by `capitalization`. The problem is that Linux paths are apparently `case-sensitive` so you need to rename your Controller files from `"config.php" to "config.php".`